# jqgrid filter removes one row on load once

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filter

I constructed one grid using jqgrid and I have enabled filtering. The datatype retrieved is json and i'm using the loadonce feature. When I apply some filters it appears that it always hides on record. I'm using a grid pager just to have the extra buttons that i want to add on the grid and i'm removing the gridpager buttons (next, last, etc..). I removed the pager to see if there was any conflict but still i get the same error. When the grid loads i'm getting 'View 1 - 7 of 7' and i can see 7 records, when I'm applying a filter the output is 'View 1 - 3 of 4'. Which means that 4 records match the filter but it keeps displaying only 3. Now if i clear the filters i get 'View 1 - 6 of 7', again one record is missing. I checked the table with firebug to see if the record is hidden but still nothing. I tried firefox, chrome, IE and in all browsers i get the same error. The jqgrid version is 4.1.1. Any clues why this is happening?

Below you can see the code:

```
jq($grid).jqGrid({
    url: $url,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'Get',
    colNames: colNamesList,
    colModel: $colModel,
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems:false,
        id: "id",
    },
    rowNum: -1, 
    width: jq(document).width()-20,
    height: 200,
    pager: $pagerId,
    viewrecords: true,
    fixed: true,
    shrinkToFit: false,
    loadonce: true, 
    caption: $caption,
    beforeRequest: function(){
        if (!initialized) {
            jq(blockElement).block({ message: '<h1 class="loadingMsg">Grid is loading, please wait...</h1>' });
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function(data){
        if (loadCompleteCallback != null){
            loadCompleteCallback(data);
        }

        if (!initialized) {
            jq.jGrowl('"' + $caption + '" Grid loaded.', {header:'Load Notification'});
            jq(blockElement).unblock();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
});

        if (!initialized) {
            jq.jGrowl('"' + $caption + '" Grid loaded.', {header:'Load Notification'});
            jq(blockElement).unblock();
            initialized = true;
        }
    }
});

jq($grid).jqGrid('filterToolbar',{
    stringResult: true,
    searchOnEnter : false
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't understand the following: *why you return from the server one row which you never want to show*? Is it not easier to remove the data already on the server side? If it is not possible you can remove the row inside of `loadComplete`. By the way in the current code I can't see where you set custom filter which makes one row of the grid invisible.

One more remark: You should never use `rowNum: -1`. Only positive values (like `rowNum: 10000`) are permitted. It's especially important if you use `loadonce: true` which chynges the `datatype` to `'local'` after the first filling of the grid. The usage of negative `rowNum` are not permitted.

Comment: @user944643: Could you post the exact example inclusive the JSON data returned from the server? You wrote always about the filtering one record but never describe *how* you do this. Which filter you set and in which way? Could you post enough data and code so that other could reproduce the described problem?

Comment: Hi, all the data returned are needed and all data are presented to the grid. when filtering is used then jqgrid is loosing one record from the data. I know that loadonce is retrieving the data once from the server and then these data are used as local data. The issue is that after filtering one record is always missing from the results. Regarding the rowNum: -1 the document does not specify that it cannot take negative value, when a negative value is passed all the data are displayed and it seems to be working, at least before filtering. I'll check it again tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: The error occurs, both afer filtering and after sorting. So for instance if i have in the grid the following rows 

    A C B D E and the caption will show "View 1-5 of 5"

after sorting i will have 

    B C D E and the caption will show: "View 1-4 of 5"

Another scenario is the following 

Grid contains the following rows

    AAA AAB ABB CC  and the caption will show: "View 1-4 of 4"

If I enter the filter term "A" i will get the following

    AAA AAB then the caption will show: "View 1-2 of 3"

There is always a record missing, only after sorting and after filtering

Comment: @user944643: If you read the  description of the documentation of the `rowNum` option [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) you will find that the sentence *"Set this parameter to -1 (unlimited) to disable this checking."* is **removed**. Before version 3.7.2 (before introducing of local sorting and filtering and the `loadonce` option) it was allowed. Later not more. It is definitively wrong if you use local data or `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: Hi Oleg, I changed the rowNum to the number of the maximum results that are received and the problem is resolved. The strange think is why it works when the gird is loaded and it displays all the records and it breaks down after filtering or sorting. Anyway i am assuming that this will be fixed in future versions of jqgrid in order to display all the row. Again thanks!

Comment: @user944643: You re welcome! I can repeat that I don't think that it is jqGrid bug. Parameter `rowNum: x` means that the number of rows in the grid will be between 0 and `x`. If you would use `rownumbers:true` you will see even negative row numbers in case of `rowNum: -1`. jqGrid makes no error correction. If you would use `rowNum: "bla bla"` or `rowNum: Inf` or  `rowNum: function() {}` you will also have many problem. You should just use correct type and value range for all parameters of jqGrid.